# How did I get into the private beta without commiting?

Tags: support, area-51, beta-phase, beta-sites, private-beta

Yesterday, the the DeepWeb.SE proposal went into private beta. I knew this because I got the following notification:

> private beta invitation
>   This proposal has entered private beta. Click here to join.

So I visited the site, created my account there and started participating. However, I had **not** commited to the site or followed the proposal on area51. As you can see in [my area51 profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/135970/gin-san?tab=stats), the Deep Web proposal doesn't show up in the *Current Commitment* or the *Followed* section.

According to all sources on the topic I found around here, the only way to access a private beta is having commited to the site prior to the beta or receiving an invitation from a commited member. I don't know any of the active participants of the Deep Web private beta, and I didn't get an invitation email either, but only the notification. So I doubt someone personally invited me.

So how did I get into that private beta?

Comment: So, the actual question you have is - why did you get the notification in the first place, right? (btw - anyone can join the private beta - the link to the site on the proposal page on area51 will give you access)

Comment: Yes indeed. Really? Every source I found on that topic said you needed to have commited to the site or be invited in order to enter the private beta

Comment: Those requirements were relaxed some time ago - if someone is interested enough in a site that they would click a link in the area51 proposal, then why shouldn't they participate?

Comment: I agree (even though I also like the concept of a commitment in order to ensure vivid participation), I was just confused since me being able to enter without fulfilling either of the two requirements contradicted the information I found about private beta sites

Comment: Notification or email?

Comment: @ShadowWizard What do you mean?

Comment: Users of private beta site can invite other users via email. Maybe that's the case, though you said notification, maybe you actually meant email, so I just want to be sure.

Comment: @ShadowWizard No I meant the notification, as stated in the question. In the last paragraph I also explicitly stated that I didn't get an email

Comment: Dupe since the answer is there: "private beta notifications will be sent to people who committed to a proposal **or followed it during the definition phase**"

Comment: This doesn't sound like a duplicate for me. Another question asks about notification feature request which was already implemented (so it's already redundant), this asks why the invitation e-mail was sent despite not being committed to the proposal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that you did not commit to the proposal - but you did follow it, in January of this year, so some time ago.

We notify all the people who either committed on followed a proposal when it does get launched - as these all showed interest in the existence of the site and we want to give a site the best possible start with as many interested users as possible.

Comment: Really? I can't remember that ... how do you know that? I can't see it in my area51 profile ...

Comment: The UI doesn't really show following info, but the DB record is there...

Comment: Sneaky °A° Alright then, thank you! Buuuut it does show me other proposals I followed ...

Comment: Followed or committed to?

Comment: followed. It shows me I have 12 proposals I'm following, but Deep Web isn't among them. Or is that because it has left the proposal phase?

Comment: I will dig deeper then - could be you "unfollowed" and the notification code doesn't take notice.

Comment: Very interesting. I don't think I've ever unfollowed a proposal though ... well it's not that important after all, I was just curious. If you find out why it's not showing up on my profile, let me know °v°

Comment: @MoritzLost when you go [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87978?phase=definition), do you see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dw0Gw.png) or [that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vbKCI.png)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It says 'unfollow'

Comment: @MoritzLost so it means you're following it... UI is correct, all is good. :-)

Comment: @MoritzLost as for not appearing in profile, once a proposal is launched (as private beta) it won't appear in profiles anymore as being followed. Oded can confirm that's the expected behavior and not a bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I expect that's true. It does makes sense to me.